# Putting values of same dictionary keys in one group in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration, key-value

I have two lists:

`list1=[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]`
`list2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','k','o','n','q','t','z','w','l']`

```
dictionary=dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

I would like to output values of the same keys in one for each key such as it will print like this:

```
 0 ['a','b','c']  
 1 ['d','e']  
 2 ['f','k']  
 3 ['o','n']  
 4 ['q','t']  
 5 ['z','w','l']
```

I wrote following code  to do that but it does not work as I think

```
for k,v in dictionary.items():  

     print (k,v)
```

Could you tell me how to fix code so that I can get above intended results, please ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `dictionary`?

Comment: could you show where you create your dictionary?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it in the first time, I have updated my code @Legman

Comment: See also: [How to group data by labels and return a list of calculated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311239/putting-values-of-same-dictionary-keys-in-one-group-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your code:

```
dictionary = dict(zip(list1, list2))
```

creates the dictionary:

```
{0: 'c', 1: 'e', 2: 'k', 3: 'n', 4: 't', 5: 'l'}
```

which loses all but the last value in each group. You need to process the zipped lists to construct the grouped data. Two ways are with `itertools.groupby()` or with a `defaultdict(list)`, shown here.

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) of lists to group the items with keys from `list1` and values from `list2`. Pair the items from each list with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1=[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]
list2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','k','o','n','q','t','z','w','l']

d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)

for k in sorted(d):
    print('{} {!r}'.format(k, d[k]))
```

Output:

```
0 ['a', 'b', 'c']
1 ['d', 'e']
2 ['f', 'k']
3 ['o', 'n']
4 ['q', 't']
5 ['z', 'w', 'l']
```

Since items in a dictionary are unordered, the output is sorted by key.

Answer (score 3):

The code you've shown does not look anything like what you described.

That aside, you can group values of the same key together by first zipping the lists and then grouping values of the same key using a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(list1, list2):
    d[k].append(v)
print(d)
# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {0: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 1: ['d', 'e'], 2: ['f', 'k'], 3: ['o', 'n'], 4: ['q', 't'], 5: ['z', 'w', 'l']})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertool.groupby` for a concise, one line solution:

```
import itertools
list1=[0,0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5]
list2=['a','b','c','d','e','f','k','o','n','q','t','z','w','l']
final_list = {a:[i[-1] for i in list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(zip(list1, list2), key=lambda x: x[0])}
for a, b in final_list.items():
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
0 ['a', 'b', 'c']
1 ['d', 'e']
2 ['f', 'k']
3 ['o', 'n']
4 ['q', 't']
5 ['z', 'w', 'l']
```